# filling rows with former numbers R

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I do have a dataframe, which is a result of a merge (all =TRUE) and looks like this one (where the merge is conducted by Groupname, ObservationName and Date, the 2 Treatment columns come from the x :

```
A <- data.frame(GroupName = c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6)),
                ObservationName = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", rep(c("delta", "epsilon"),3), rep(c("zeta", "eta", "theta"),2)),
                Date = rep(rep(seq(as.Date("2010-1-1"), as.Date("2010-3-1"), by = "month"), each =3), 2),
                Value = runif(n = 18, min = 1, max = 10),
                Treatment1 = rep(NA, 18),
                Treatment2 = rep(NA, 18))
A[c(1, 5, 6, 10, 12,13),5] <- 1
A[c(1, 5, 6, 10, 12,13),6] <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 4)
A[c( 7, 10 , 14), c(1,2,4)] <- NA
```

I would like to carry the values of my Treatment1 and Treatment 2 on. Namely I want to group my dfs by Groupname and Observationname and order it by Date column. If Treatment1 has a one in a earlier observation of that group, all later Treatments should have a one as well. In Treatment2 the numbers shall cumulate. That mean: in row 1,2,3,4  should be 1, in row 5 should be 4 (since 1 + 3) and in row 6 there should be 9 (since 1 +3+5). and so on. Thanks for help.
One of my tries with dplyr is:

```
A %>% group_by(GroupName, ObservationName) %>% 
        arrange(Date) %>% 
      mutate(Treatment1 = sum(Treatment1),
             Treatment1cm = cummax(Treatment1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

but that does not override the NAs.
The aim is to delete all the rows where only treatment1 and Treatment 2 is given, since the (or value is NA) but all information a took over.

Comment: Do you need the NAs, or could they be replaced with 0? 
 `A$Treatment1[is.na(A$Treatment1)] <- 0`  then proceed as you tried above?

Comment: using the `na.rm = TRUE` argument for `sum()` will help in the first instance.

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: Based on your question, for `Treatment2` the grouping needs to be only based on `GroupName`, right? Since we're summing `Treatment2` regardless of the `ObservationName`.